# setuid(###) followed by getuid() fails in C program with permissions bit set

Tags: c, setuid

I'm trying something very simple with setuid followed by getuid in a C program that is not working unless the user is the owner of the c program.  I am setting the permissions bit using chmod 7777 in addition to thesetuid.  Here is the C program...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int x;

  printf("Setting uid to 1111\n");
  x=setuid(1111);
  printf("setuid returned... %d\n",x);
  printf("Testing state of uid using getuid()\n");
  printf("uid: %d\n",getuid());

  return 0;
}
```

Given that 1111 is the uid of the owner of the C program (returned by id -u).
after gcc, chmod 7777 on the binary produced.

Testing as the owner works fine...

```
% suid
Setting uid to 1111
setuid returned... 0
Testing state of uid using getuid()
uid: 1112
```

and to check the permissions on the binary...

```
ls -l suid
-rwsrwsrwx 1 katman design 6852 Mar  1 17:56 suid
```

Then I become another user (same group BTW) and run the "suid" executable again...

```
% suid
Setting uid to 1111
setuid returned... 0
Testing state of uid using getuid()
uid: 57849
```

Why isn't setuid working given that the owner granted permission to do this?

Also...

Q:  If I can get this to work, I have heard that one can do a system() call to run a cshell script from a C  program like this and the shell script should run as the owner of the C program.  The uid  is "passed down" to children. True or False?

Q: If the cshell script runs a perl script which in turn runs system calls, etc... will all these offspring shells run as the owner of the parent C binary that started started the whole cascade?  IOW, is the uid "inherited" by children?

Comment: check the return value of `setuid()`!

Comment: Check (and print?) the return value from `setuid()`.  If it's not working, the error code should tell you why.  Also, you probably shouldn't have `.` in your `PATH`...it's preferable to force yourself to type `./my-program-name` if you want to run a particular version of the program in your current directory.

Comment: Why does the program print 1112 when the code has 1111?

Comment: `setuid` works for me (as non-root) only when the owner of the file is `root` and suid bit is set for the owner.

Comment: Change your `setuid` line to `if(setuid(1111) == -1) { perror("setuid"); return 1; }` and execute your code. It would tell you why it fails.

Comment: Wooowww...  I tried replacing my setuid(...) line with the suggested If(setuid(1111) == -1) {perror("setuid"); return 1;}.  It errored out with "setuid: Operation not permitted".  So I'm not permitted to use the C library function setuid ?

Comment: No, you are not permitted to execute that operation, because you don't have the proper rights.  More precisely, your running process does not have `CAP_SETUID` capability. See the [man page of `setuid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) for more information, it explains when a process is allowed to change the effective user ID. If you do `sudo chown root: ./suid && sudo chmod u+s ./suid`, then it would work.

Comment: OK, that explains it.  Thanks everyone.